# How to get the minimum and maxium number using pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, max, min

I trying to find the minimum and maximum numbers using pointers in C++ but in this code that I get from the video-sharing site gives me the wrong value. when I type 1 2 3 4 5 6 its answer is the minimum is 2 and the maximum is 2.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int value[6], * maxi, * mini, a;
    cout << "Enter six numbers with space: ";
    for (int a = 0; a < 6; a++)
        cin >> *(value + a);
    maximum = value;
    minimum = value;
    for (i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    {
        if (*(value + i) > * maximum)
            *maximum = *(value + i);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        if (*(value + i) < *minimum)
            *minimum = *(value+ i);
    }
    /* Print variable value with their memory address */
    cout << "Integer with the Maximum value = " << *minimum << ", Address of integer = " << &maximum  
 << endl;
    cout << "Integer with the minimum value = " << *minimum  << ", Address of integer = " << &minimum  
  << endl;
    return 0;
  }
```

this is the result of the code

Enter five (6) numbers separated by a space: 1 2 3 4 5 6

Integer with the largest value = 2, Address of integer = 00AFF9F4

Integer with the smallest value = 2, Address of integer = 00AFF9E8

Comment: maximum and minimum are undefined. It is very important that you use the actual code here or we will find errors that are not there :)

Comment: What @Surt said. Make a [mcve] so we can compile it too.

Comment: You made this code more complicated then needed. Also learn to use standard library, see example: https://godbolt.org/z/b4669z

Comment: I learned a lot from you guys. Thank you! More power to all of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are the complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#define N_VALUES 6

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int value[N_VALUES], *maximum, *minimum, i;
    cout << "Enter six numbers with space: ";
    for (i = 0; i < N_VALUES; i++) cin >> *(value + i);
    
    maximum = value;
    minimum = value;
    
    for (i = 1; i < N_VALUES; i++) {
        if (*(value + i) > (*maximum)) {
            maximum = (value + i);
        }
    }
    
    for (i = 1; i < N_VALUES; i++) {
        if (*(value + i) < (*minimum)) {
            minimum = (value+ i);
        }
    }
    
    /* Print variable value with their memory address */
    cout << "Integer with the Maximum value = " << *maximum << ", Address of integer = " << maximum << endl;
    cout << "Integer with the minimum value = " << *minimum  << ", Address of integer = " << minimum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You got a mistake in this loop

```
for (i = 1; i < 6; i++)
{
    if (*(value + 1) > * maximum)
        *maximum = *(value + i); <--- set max to the next value.
}
```

Should be

```
for (i = 1; i < 6; i++)
{
    if (*(value + i) > * maximum) 
        maximum = value + i; // set max to the pointer.
}
```

Comment: thanks but I mistakenly type it its letter i actually. I will edit my codes

Comment: @NewProgrammer updated answer to the next posibility.